# Why would a marketing agency require several external Google publisher accounts in our Ads.txt?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

A third party marketing agency (`Ads.Plus`) agent has contacted us via email if we would want to increase ad revenue by adding some ad codes in our pages, as well as to update our `ads.txt` file. We agreed to try their proposition for a few days, so the agent gave a long list of `ads.txt` websites/companies (788 lines to be exact) that we should add to our website's `ads.txt`. Upon closer inspection of the ads.txt entries the agent provided though, we found 60 unique Google publisher accounts, 11 of which were of type `DIRECT`, like so:

`google.com, pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0`

with the rest being `RESELLER`. Can someone please explain why Google publisher accounts should be added to our site's `ads.txt` like what the agent is asking us to do before we could implement their ads on our site? Will doing so negatively affect our own site's ads revenue (we have our own AdSense ads)?